# How to configure Sublime Text 2 ANT build script in Windows?

Tags: windows, ant, sublimetext2

I typically use Sublime Text on a Mac at work and it's fine. But I'm trying to set up Sublime Text with my Windows PC at home and keep getting errors when trying to run my build script.

Here's my project file:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "my-folder"
        }
    ],
    "build_systems":
    [
        {
            "name": "Ant",
            "cmd": ["ant"],
            "working_dir": "${project_path}"
        }
    ]
}
```

And here's the error I get:

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'ant']]
[dir:  D:\Users\****\Projects]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\]
[Finished]
```

Seems that it can't find ANT? But isn't that bundled with Sublime Text?

Answer (score 0):

Type 'ant' in your commandline. If it throws an error, then ant is not in your PATH. You'll need to install it (http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html) and then add it to your PATH environment variable.

I use Sublime, but I don't know if it packages Ant by default. If it does, just add the location of the binary to your system PATH.

Comment: Thanks. It does seem that ANT is undefined. I'm following those instructions but how do I "add it to my PATH environment variable"?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out what you mean. Just ran a build. Thanks!